# Non-linear functional form satisfying $g(x-y) = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$.

Tags: nonlinear-system

Is there a general non-linear mapping function family, which obeys this general rule:

$$g(x-y) = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}.$$

I am looking at identifying a classification of admissible kinetics relaxation functions.